# RAID 10 Configuration Settings with different disks

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, raid10

I have just started configuring a server with 4 SSD drives.

Each drive pair has the same capacity, but not the same throughout the 4 disks.

I want to use `RAID 10`, and I have tried different configurations in the Megaraid BIOS to see what would be the best configuration, without leaving unused space, to make the most out of the array.

This is the configuration I am considering using, can anyone tell me if I should be better of combining the disks in a different way? I tried having disks with the same capacity in the same span, but Megaraid would say the configuration would yeld around 44GB of unused space, so I guess this would be better.

Any insights?

[image]

Comment: If it really bothers you, buy the same capacity SSDs. You've mixed 1 TB with 1.024 TB SSDs.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Is there any problem with the approach I used? Should I go for a solution that leaves unused space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend just using the amount of space that the MegaRAID manager provides under a RAID 1+0 setup.

Yes, you will lose access to a few gigabytes of data... But understand that it's necessary to make the array function.

Ideally, you'd be using equal-sized disks, but the hardware RAID controller needs to use the lowest common capacity to ensure that the setup will work.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What is the benefit of 1+0 versus the configuration I have?